# VIM ctrl+tab to change tab shifts cursor backwards

Tags: vim, tabs

I found this code the forum to make my life easier when switching between tabs and I placed it in my ~/.vimrc.  Happily, it works well.  Unfortunately, whenever I ctrl+tab to change tab, the cursor moves back one character.  Can anyone help me keep the cursor in one place?

```
set showtabline=2
:nmap <C-S-tab> :tabprevious<cr>
:nmap <C-tab> :tabnext<cr>
:nmap <C-t> :tabnew<cr>
:map <C-t> :tabnew<cr>
:map <C-S-tab> :tabprevious<cr>
:map <C-tab> :tabnext<cr>
:map <C-w> :tabclose<cr>
:imap <C-S-tab> <ESC>:tabprevious<cr>i
:imap <C-tab> <ESC>:tabnext<cr>i
:imap <C-t> <ESC>:tabnew<cr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything romainl said is good advice, in particular that tabs are not supposed to work as one-to-one proxies for files, like in other editors. Learn to use buffers, and your life will be easier. They're really very simple: all you really need is `:set hidden`, `:ls`, `:bn`, `:bp`, maybe some mappings like the ones you're setting up for tabs, and a bit of the Vim help.

That said, romainl's mapping will fail at the end of a line. A better solution uses `<C-o>`, which takes you out of insert mode temporarily for one command, and takes into account stuff like end-of-line behavior. You could use:

`:imap <C-tab> <C-o>:tabnext<cr>`

Comment: what ARE tabs for, then?  :)  i've been using vim for years and always found buffers cumbersome, but tabs with several splits in them work well

Answer (score 2):

The cursor moves back one character because that's how `i` works. Technically, you can change

```
:imap <C-tab> <ESC>:tabnext<cr>i
```

to

```
:imap <C-tab> <ESC>:tabnext<cr>li
```

***but*** staying in insert mode is not a very good idea. If you can't help it, I'd suggest you remove the three `imap` from your `~/.vimrc` to force you to use Vim correctly.

By the way…

- You don't need that leading `:` in your `~/.vimrc`:

  ```
  map <C-t> :tabnew<cr>
  ```
- You don't really need those `:map` because you already have `nmap` (and `imap`, but it should go).
- `<C-t>` is very useful, both in insert mode (indents the current line) and in normal mode (goes back in the tagstack). You shouldn't override it like that.
- `<C-S-Tab>` will probabbly not work in a terminal.
- Tabs are not designed as 1-to-1 proxies for files and thus should not be used as such. You should use buffers instead.